# IOS for Cisco 6509/7609

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-6500, cisco-7600

Good morning,

I need to move one SUP7203bXL from a 6509 chassis to a 7609. Now the SUP has the IOS: 
s72033-adventerprisek9_wan-mz.122-33.SXJ.bin

I would like to have the IOS: c7600s72033-advipservicesk9-mz.122-33.SRE1.bin running on the 7609 router. Is this IOS compatible with 6509, so I can update the IOS on the 6509 and then move the SUP?

What should I do?

Another question, does the IOS s72033-adventerprisek9_wan-mz.122-33.SXJ.bin allow mac access-lists? I can create them but can't apply it to an interface ... Should I take into account something else?

Comment: I apologize for not following up on your comment sooner.  Life got fairly busy yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to have the IOS: c7600s72033-advipservicesk9-mz.122-33.SRE1.bin running on the 7609 router. Is this IOS compatible with 6509, so I can update the IOS on the 6509 and then move the SUP?

You're speaking about a subject which is very confusing, and I apologize.  For years, you could mostly get away with saying the biggest difference between a Catalyst 6500 chassis and Cisco 7600 chassis was the paint.

Times changed, starting in IOS 12.2SRB.  Now, you are strongly discouraged from running IOS 12.2SRB (or after) on a Catalyst 6500 chassis, because [Cisco split support for Catalyst 6500 and Cisco 7600 chassis](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/7600-series-routers/prod_bulletin0900aecd805df25d.html) into different software images and business units.  There were business reasons for splitting support for Catalyst 6500 and Cisco 7600 branded systems.  If you feel that you must run 7600 12.2SRB or later on a Catalyst 6500, please speak with your Cisco account manager; he should be able to contact the 7600 BU and get discussions going.

> does the IOS s72033-adventerprisek9_wan-mz.122-33.SXJ.bin allow mac access-lists? I can create them but can't apply it to an interface ... Should I take into account something else?

It should, with some linecard limitations.  Quoting the [LAN Switching command reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/lanswitch/command/reference/lsw_book/lsw_m1.pdf):

*For the Cisco 7600 series platform when ES20 or ES40 line cards are used, only the `{permit | deny} {src-mac mask | any} {dest-mac mask | any}` part of the command syntax applies. If an extended MAC Access Control List is created using the `[protocol [vlan vlan] [cos value]]` options, these options are ignored.*

These options apply to LAN cards.  If you were using an OSM or other "WAN" card, the issues are different.

Comment: By the moment, i need to upload the IOS to the SUP (the one in hot stand-by) so then move the SUP from the 6500 chassis to the 7600 where it will run... On the other hand, if the s72033-adventerprisek9_wan-mz.122-33.SXJ.bin can be run on the 7600 i can change the IOS after moving the SUP but as you said, years ago the 6500 and 7600 were the same but after 12.2SRB things changed...Now  i'm not sure if the IOS i mentioned can run in both chassis

Comment: @rs1983, I want to research something... can I answer tomorrow?